# Reference Request - The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Is there an intuitive/straigh-forward proof of the Weierstra/ss Approximation Theorem? If so, where can I find it?

I heard that Lebesgue gave a simple proof. Is this true, and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Just not to confuse with other theorems, do you talk about the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Bernstein's proof is pretty intuitive and constructive.

Comment: @Yanko I am referring to just the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

Comment: @user10354138 What motivates the use of the Bernstein Polynomials?

Comment: The lattice version is quite easy, and it essentially only needs the fact that $\sqrt\bullet\ $ has a Taylor expansion that converges uniformly on $(\varepsilon,1]$.

Comment: @user109871 They come pretty naturally in terms of simulation (indeed Bernstein's own proof dresses up like one).  For each $x$, estimate $f(x)$ by sampling $[0,1]$ using scaled binomial distribution with probability $x$, $$B_n(f)(x):=\mathbb{E}[f(n^{-1}Binomial(n,x))]$$ then law of large number says $$n^{-1}Binomial(n,x)\xrightarrow{a.s.} x$$

Comment: (cont'd) so you mostly sample points very close to $x$, hence there is not much error from sampling too far off.  Also, for very near $x$, uniform continuity of $f$ says sampling sufficiently near $x$ isn't that different from plugging the value $f(x)$.

Comment: A straight-forward proof of the more general Stone-Weierstrass Theorem in "General Topology" by R. Engelking  in under 2 pages, from 3.2.18 (The Dini Theorem) (Chapter 3, Section 2, Prop. 18), and  two more preliminary Lemmas 3.2.19 and 3.2.20, and the S-W Theorem itself in 3.2.21. Note that  "compact space" means "compact Hausdorff space" in this book.